# How can I convert ISO format timestamp to UTC and the compare it with ISO format timestamp

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime

I am writing a program where users will have to input date and time in ISO format.

```
2010-12-03T23:10:00
```

Users will enter date and time according to their timezone. I need to compare this date and time with another ISO formatted date and time which will be in UTC.

How can I convert user inputted date and time to UTC first?

I can achieve it using the following code:

```
def local_to_utc(local_time):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
    conv2epoch = time.mktime(time.strptime(local_time, fmt))
    epoch2utc = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(conv2epoch).strftime(fmt)
    return epoch2utc

dateutil.parser.parse(local_to_utc('2010-12-03T23:10:00Z'))
```

Are there any easier ways?